# evil & org-time-stamp-inactive at end of line in normal mode

Tags: org-mode, evil, spacemacs

I use evil (via spacemacs) and I want to insert a time stamp at the end of the current line in org-mode. Alas the end-of-line in evil normal mode is not the same as in vanilla emacs, so that pressing `$` and then calling `org-time-stamp-inactive` inserts the timestamp **before the last character** in that line.

I can work around this by switching into emacs mode first, but this is unsatisfactory, because in emacs mode I have entirely different key bindings, whereas I try to fully embrace the spacemacs evil defaults.

Any suggestions how to handle this? Perhaps a way to move the cursor one character further in normal mode? A command prefix that forces the execution of the following command at the "true" end of line while not moving the point at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evil has not one, but two settings to customize the behaviour of point at EOL:

- `evil-move-beyond-eol` decides whether movement beyond EOL is possible at all.  When set to `t`, you can move towards it, but things like `i` or `a` will still put cursor back after exiting insert state.
- `evil-move-cursor-back` is a superset of the above as it disables moving cursor back, both after normal movement commands and after exiting insert state.  If you're after more Emacs-like behaviour, set it to `nil`.