# org-mode + evil: insert heading, set cursor to line ending, and change to insert mode?

Tags: org-mode, evil

I am using spacemacs which contains `org-mode` and `evil`. Whenever I insert a heading (either `org-insert-heading`, `org-insert-heading-after-current` or `org-insert-subheading`), I have to do two extra actions: move cursor to the end of line, change to insert mode to start typing. How do I get these two actions done automatically for all the insert heading functions?

What I am thinking now is to write wraper functions for these functions, and then redefine the shortcut keys. But wouldn't there be a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `org-M-RET-may-split-line` to `nil` via:

`(setq org-M-RET-may-split-line nil)` in your `.spacemacs` or `.emacs` file.

look at the documentation for `org-insert-heading` with `SPC h d f` in spacemacs or `C-h f` in emacs. Setting that variable to nil will tell org to never split the line on an insert.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

The following function should meet your goal:

```
(defun my-insert-new-sibling-after-current (&optional force-heading)
 (interactive)
 (end-of-line)
 (if force-heading ; is set to t
     (cond
         ((org-on-heading-p) (org-insert-heading-after-current))
         (t                  (progn 
                                (org-speed-move-safe (quote outline-previous-visible-heading))
                                (end-of-line)
                                (org-insert-heading-respect-content nil))))
     (cond
         ((org-on-heading-p) (org-insert-heading-after-current))
         ((org-at-item-p)    (org-meta-return))
         (t                  (org-return))))
 (evil-append nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed to in [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20149) answer, setting `evil-move-beyond-eol` to non-nil, although not very vimesque, would allow you to move pass the last character, fixing the unwanted behavior you're having.